# Chinese encoding issue

Tags: html, character-encoding, asp-classic

I send some Chinese character via query string

[image: screenshot]

but the page that receives them does not display them correctly. In particular, it must display them in `<input type="text" />`. How to settlem down the problem?

Comment: What encoding your page is in?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use UTF-8:

```
Response.Codepage = 65001
Response.CharSet = "UTF-8"
```

Change your input tag to something like:

```
<input type="text" value="<%=Server.HTMLEncode(Request.QueryString("word"))%>" />
```

Server.HTMLEncode will prevent [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attacks and also help browsers render the correct characters.

If you still have issues, you will want to add the following in your before the `</head>` in your HTML.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```